# check if websocket server is down

Tags: websocket

I'm building an internal monitoring site that mainly receives data. The site is intended to be  open continuously and shown on a dedicated monitor. I'm using websockets.

I wonder how the client best detects when the server is down? The only approach I can think of is to ping the server on an interval?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean on client side and if client would normally keep websocket connection to server open then you should handle onclose() event.

To keep connection from closing because of timeouts etc, if you expect to have long periods of inactivity, it's probably simpler to make server send simple 'still alive' message on regular intervals which would reset watchdog timer on client. If no such messages received for significantly long time client should attempt to reconnect.